# Django queryset get exact manytomany lookup

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a pk list of instances of Tag model, say

```
pk_list = [10, 6, 3]
```

I have another model with m2m field of tags and an instance that contains exactly 3 tags (of above pks).

```
class Node(models.Model):
    ...
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='nodes')
```

I'd like to retrieve a Node that contains exact set of tags as specified in my pk_list. When I do

```
Node.objects.filter(tags__in=pk_list)
```

it returns a list of three same instances

```
[<Node: My node title>, <Node: My node title>, <Node: My node title>]
```

Calling .get() doesn't work cause it have to return a single instance, obviously.

So, how do I retrieve a single instance?
I must note that if my pk_list was different eg. [10, 6] or [10, 6, 3, 7] then I must receive nothing. I need an exact matching.

Thanks

Comment: I was going to answer, then noticed that post is me!

Comment: Thanks for the comments, and sorry for duplicate, I didn't do it on purpose.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

One approach is to use chain of filters:

```
node_query = Node.objects.all()
pk_list = [10, 6, 3]

for pk in pk_list:
    node_query = node_query.filter(tags=pk)
```

Now node_query will match node, that has **at least** three tags with pk 10, 6, 3. To exact matching of three tags:

**UPDATE**:
Thanks to [@janos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/641955/janos) and [@Adrián López](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1959899/adrian-lopez), the correct answer is:

```
from django.db.models import Count

pk_list = [10, 6, 3]
node_query = Node.objects.annotate(count=Count('tags')).filter(count=len(pk_list))

for pk in pk_list:
    node_query = node_query.filter(tags__pk=pk)
```