# Filter objects by manytomany relation

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

Can't figure out a good way to filter by many to many relation.

```
class Scheduler(models.Model):
    weekhours = models.ManyToManyField('WeekHour', related_name='schedulers')

    def get_active_products_by_weekhour(self,weekhour):
        return Product.objects.filter(scheduler__in=WeekHour.objects.get(hour=weekhour).schedulers.all())


class WeekHour(models.Model):
    hour = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Hour in week (0 - 7*24')
```

Now suppose I have a list of numbers, for example:

```
hours = [2,4,6]
```

I want to find a Scheduler which has this exact set of `WeekHour` objects with these `hour` values.

So it returns scheduler if and only if there is some which has this weekhours set `[WeekHour(hour=2),WeekHour(hour=4),WeekHour(hour=6)]`. So the number of related WeekHours must be the same as a size of the list. In this case 3.

Is this possible using Django orm and not using cycles?

EDIT:

What about this?

```
weekhours_set = [Weekhour.objects.get(hour=x) for x in hours]
scheduler = Scheduler.objects.filter(weekhours__exact=weekhours_set)
```

This returns:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

Answer (score 0):

`__exact` is expecting the same type as the field type.

You should consider using `__in` and then chaining Q expressions on `operator.and_` to *filter* the *exact* object that has a relation to the ids of all the related objects:

```
import operator
from django.db.models import Q

weekhours_set = Weekhour.objects.filter(hour__in=hours).values_list('id', flat=True)
schedulers = Scheduler.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, [Q(weekhours__id=id) for id in weekhours_set]))
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work correctly. For testing purposes I have two scheduler objects. First has weekhours = [WeekHour(hour=2),WeekHour(hour=4),WeekHour(hour=6)] and the second has all weekhours possible ( WeekHour(hour=<from 1 to 7*24)) and it returns both. But the hours is [2,4,6] so I want to return only the first. The WeekHour set should be exact.

Comment: And schedulers are distinct (there are no two schedulers with the same WeekHour set).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't return anything. If I print weekhours_set, it returns <QuerySet [2, 4, 6]>. Should it be queryset?

Comment: You probably want to `filter` in a `for`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324362/django-queryset-get-exact-manytomany-lookup