# Django find exact match for Many To Many relationship

Tags: sql, django, psql

Lets say tat I have such a model:

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    sid = models.CharField(
        max_length=34,
        primary_key=True
    )
    members = models.ManyToManyField(to=User)
```

I would like to find a Conversation that is connected exactly/only with users `[1,2]`

I tried this:

```
conversation = Conversation.objects.filter(
            members__in=[1, 2]
        )
```

But it returns all conversation that are connected with either user 1, or 2.

I tried this: [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324362/django-queryset-get-exact-manytomany-lookup) but It returns empty queryset.

Answer (score 5):

We can count how many `members` match the list, and check if that includes all the `members`:

```py
from django.db.models import Count, Q

members = [1,2]
members_len = len(set(members))

Conversation.objects.annotate(
    total_members=Count('members'),
    matching_members=Count('members', filter=Q(members__in=members))
).filter(
    matching_members=members_len,
    total_members=members_len
)
```

This thus will retrieve `Converstion`s that contain *all* members in the `members` list, and *only* these members (so not a superset, nor a subset).

Or for pre [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0) installations:

```py
from django.db.models import Case, Count, When

members = [1,2]
members_len = len(set(members))

Conversation.objects.annotate(
    total_members=Count('members'),
    matching_members=Count(Case(
        When(members__in=members, then='members'),
        default=None
    ))
).filter(
    matching_members=members_len,
    total_members=members_len
)
```

Comment: total_members is repeated

Comment: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'total_members' into field. Choices are: members,

Comment: @Przemek: sorry, that should have been an `.annotate(..)` apparently there was a brainfreeze when writing this answer.

Comment: Should not it be total_members=Count('members') instead of total_members=Sum('members')?

Comment: @Przemek: why would we `Sum(..)` members? Notice the `filter=Q(members__in=members)`, so we count the number of `members` in the list of members we are interesting in.

Comment: @Przemek: then you likely use a pre 2.0 Django version?

Comment: I use Django 1.11

Comment: @Przemek: then we will have to do the `Case`-`When` work ourseleves :s