# How to filter a django queryset with multiple ManyToMany references

Tags: django, django-models

This is the shape of my models.

```
class SomeModel(model):
    some_field = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

class OtherModel(Model):
    list_of_some_models = models.ManyToManyField(SomeModel)
```

I have a dictionary like this, where each element in the list is the SomeModel pk:

```
{
    "list_of_some_models": [1, 10, 12, 20]
}
```

I would like to check if there is already a record that has a relationship with SomeModel of id 1, 10, 12 and 20.

is it possible?

Comment: try this `OtherModel.objects.filter(list_of_some_models__in=[1, 10, 12, 20])`

Comment: it returns 4 identical instances of OtherModel because I guess it finds 1 OtherModel for each pk in the list... I would like to find 1 OtherModel that simultaneously has relationship with all the 4 SomeModel

Comment: use `.distinct()` to remove the duplicates.

Comment: it does not work, because if I do OtherModel.objects.filter(list_of_some_models__in=[10]) it will find the OtherModel that has list_of_some_models = [1, 10, 12, 20]

Answer (score 0):

It is duplicate of [Django queryset get exact manytomany lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324362/django-queryset-get-exact-manytomany-lookup)

this partially solves my problem, the issue is that if there are too many elements in the list_of_some_models the database complains about the number of joins.